# override existed tailwind classes

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

can i add another style to a tailwind class ?

for example i want the default style for the class `flex` to be `display:flex; gap:6px`

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      flex: { display: "flex", alignItems: "center", gap: "6px" }, //something like that
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `.flex` rule in your CSS that has the other properties you'd like to add to `flex` other than the `display` declaration:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<style type="text/tailwindcss">
  @layer utilities {
    .flex {
      gap: 6px;
      align-items: center;
    }
  }
</style>

<div class="flex">
  <div class="size-10 bg-red-500"></div>
  <div class="size-8 bg-green-500"></div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could [add the properties in a Tailwind plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#static-utilities) like:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  plugins: [
    tailwind.plugin(({ addUtilities }) => {
      addUtilities({
        '.flex': {
          gap: '6px',
          alignItems: 'center',
        },
      });
    }),
  ],
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div class="flex">
  <div class="size-10 bg-red-500"></div>
  <div class="size-8 bg-green-500"></div>
</div>
```