# How can i overwrite a custom tailwind css , which is used in the router outlet

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, react-router-dom

in my project i used below custom css in tailwind
[custom css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPLww.png)
and added it to the outlet of react router
[outlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seaPr.png)
so it applies to every page within the homelayout, but i need to overwirte that css in the hero section of landing page. how can i do it??

i tried making another custom css in tailwind and tried adding it in the hero section, but didn't change,
what i expect from this that i want to extend my hero section through out the screen, which was avoided by my first custom css by adding padding, and max-width. I want to overwrite that css and make it extend throughout the screen,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: is thie anwser ?https://stackoverflow.com/a/78114890/21984883